# Reverse Proxy Not Displaying Content Externally but Working Internally

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Having a problem with getting the reverse proxy to work correctly. Internal reverse proxy works great. When I try to get it from WAN, running into problems.

Here is what I did:

1) Setup NGINX using easyengine - working / displaying sites correctly

2) Guacamole Server using docker install - working / displaying the application correctly

3) Reverse Proxy the guac server internally to IP: 192.168.1.31/guac - working correctly

4) Reverse Proxy the guac server externally to domain: abc.com/guac - blank page with correct HTML output (same as HTML output on the internal site)

Here are the settings I am using both on the internal IP and domain name:

```
location /guac {
    proxy_pass http://10.10.1.3:8080/guacamole/;
    proxy_buffering off;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /guac/;


    #access_log off;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush off;
    sendfile on;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;

    client_max_body_size 8m;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;
}
```

I have this set-up on another server and it's been working fine, not sure what problem could be causing this? Only difference on the other server was I did manual letsencrypt + nginx install instead of auto-generation with easyengine.

No errors in the NGINX error log.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT1:
Here is the full site-enabled config file

```
server {
    server_name abc.com   www.abc.com;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/abc.com.access.log rt_cache; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/abc.com.error.log;


    root /var/www/abc.com/htdocs;



    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    include common/php.conf;      

    include common/locations.conf;
    include /var/www/abc.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;



    location /guac {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.3:8080/guacamole/;
        proxy_buffering off;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /guac/;


    #access_log off;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush off;
    sendfile on;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;

    client_max_body_size 8m;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;

    }

}
```

and here is the config file for the local IP that is working correctly

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location /guac {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.3:8080/guacamole;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /guac/;


        access_log off;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        tcp_nopush off;
        sendfile on;
        client_body_buffer_size 10K;

        client_max_body_size 8m;
        client_body_timeout 12;
        keepalive_timeout 15;
        send_timeout 10;
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "blank out put with the correct HTML"?  Do you mean the HTML doesn't include some sort of content it's supposed to display?  Also, i fall to see how that config can be for either setup you describe; it includes neither the ip nor the domain name you mention in the text.  So I mean to say, can you show a more accurate config example that isn't working?

Comment: Should have clarified, sorry. When you view source from abc.com/guac, the correct HTML is displayed, same as it is when you check on 192.168.1.31/guac. The difference is that nothing else loads from abc.com/guac but everything works fine on the local IP/guac. I'm going to add the full code to the original post now.

Comment: Did you notice that one has a slash at the end of the proxy_pass and one doesn't?  I think this subtle difference has a significant effect on proxying.

Comment: I have tried it with and without the slash but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but taking out the line:

```
    include common/locations.conf;
```

fixed the issue